# Ender 3 Pro - "Pause at Height" automatically resumes after a few seconds

Tags: creality-ender-3, g-code

I recently bought an Ender 3 Pro, and while I'm super happy with it, there's one issue I'm having with it.

When I set "Pause at height" to a specific layer in Cura, the print will pause at that height, but as soon as it pauses the nozzle heats right back up and the print continues. It's like it pauses for only 30 seconds.

Here's the G-code for the pause command generated by Cura:

```
;MESH:NONMESH  
G0 F300 X115.454 Y119.213 Z1.96  
G0 F9000 X117.5 Y120.392  
;TIME_ELAPSED:283.376298  
;TYPE:CUSTOM  
;added code by post processing  
;script: PauseAtHeight.py  
;current layer: 6  
M83 ; switch to relative E values for any needed retraction  
G1 F1500 E-10  
G1 F300 Z2.96 ; move up a millimeter to get out of the way  
G1 F9000 X190 Y190  
G1 F300 Z15 ; too close to bed--move to at least 15mm  
M104 S0 ; standby temperature  
M117 CHANGE  
M0 ; Do the actual pause  
M109 S200 ; resume temperature  
G1 F1500 E10  
G1 F1500 E-10  
G1 F300 Z2.96  
G1 F9000 X116.604 Y120.251  
G1 F300 Z1.96 ; move back down to resume height  
G1 F1500 E10  
G1 F1200 ; restore extrusion feedrate  
M82 ; switch back to absolute E values  
G92 E256.16251  
;LAYER:6  
;TYPE:WALL-INNER  
;MESH:Super Curcan.stl
```

Anyone ever run into this issue?

Comment: I heard in a YouTube video that M0 (the pause command) doesn't work in the Ender 3 Pro firmware. It didn't work for me, either. I guess this confirms a stock firmware Ender 3 ignores the pause command.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (Cura v4.9.1). What fixed it for me was switching to a different **Method**.

On the screen where you set up the pause, the 3rd dropbox is **Method**. Set this to `BQ (M25)`. That did the trick for me.

As I understand it, it mimics a pause like what you get with the pause you would execute using the menu on the printer.